# Creating flutter sliders dynamically

Tags: flutter

For instance, I have a list of lengths 20. I want to create sliders dynamically depending on the list length. My main problem is on changing the values of each slider independently. As of now I have the sliders but when I slide one all the sliders are changed ,they a appear as one

Comment: post your code then

Comment: As can be seen in the [flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html), the value of the slider can be stored. My guess is that right now you're using a single variable which each slider 'reads' and 'writes' to, causing all of them to synchronize. You could instead use a list of (in your example) 20 slider values, and update each one accordingly when the linked slider changes its value.

It's all still speculation, though, without any code available

Comment: Follow the link [slider](http://www.fluttertpoint.com/slider-in-flutter/), And let me know any issue.